# Vue JS 3 "Scroll" scroll listening

Tags: vuejs3

I want to set an active button in the menu based on scroll events using Vue.js 3. I also want to scroll the "buttonContainerRef" accordingly. However, there are some mistakes in my current behavior. How can I resolve this?

Things I want to achieve:

When a button is clicked, I can perform "scrollIntoView" for the corresponding menu.
As the scroll moves, I update the ":data-href="list.slug"" value to "state.active."
Based on the "state.active" value, I want to handle the scroll event for the "buttonContainerRef."

```
<template>
<div class="flex overflow-x-scroll overflow-y-hidden h-12 bg-white px-2" ref="buttonContainerRef">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-center flex-nowrap">
              <button class="group-item outline-none" @click.prevent="scrollTo(list.slug)"
                      :class="{ 'group-selected': list.slug === state.active }"
                      :data-href="list.slug"
                      ref="buttonListRef"
                      v-for="list in state.list">{{ list.name }}
              </button>
            </div>
</div>

<!--Content-->

        <div class="relative bg-white z-10 dark:bg-slate-800 shadow-lg overflow-auto ring-1 ring-slate-900/5 -my-px" ref="scrollContainer">
          <div class="relative" v-for="list in state.list" :key="list.slug" :data-href="list.slug" ref="listRef">
            <div class="sticky top-0 px-4 py-3 flex items-center font-semibold text-sm text-slate-900 dark:text-slate-200 bg-slate-50/90 dark:bg-slate-700/90 backdrop-blur-sm ring-1 ring-slate-900/10 dark:ring-black/10">
              {{ list.name }}
            </div>
            <div class="divide-y dark:divide-slate-200/5">
              <div class="flex items-center gap-4 p-4 " v-for="menu in list.menus">
                <img class="w-12 h-12 rounded-sm" :src="menu.image" alt="">
                <div class="flex flex-col">
                  <strong class="text-slate-900 text-sm font-medium dark:text-slate-200">{{ menu.name }}</strong>
                  <small>{{ menu.content }}</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Content-->
</template>
<script setup>
import {onBeforeUnmount, onMounted, reactive, ref, watch} from "vue";
const state = reactive({
  active: 'advantageous-menus',
  list: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Advantageous Menus',
      slug: 'advantageous-menus',
      menus: [
        {
          name: 'Breakfast Menu',
          slug: 'breakfast-menu',
          image: 'image-url',
          content: 'Start your day with delicious breakfast options.',
          price: '20 TL'
        },
        {
          name: 'Daily Special Menu',
          slug: 'daily-special-menu',
          image: 'image-url',
          content: 'Surprise yourself with our changing daily specials.',
          price: '25 TL'
        }
      ]
    },
    // ... (similar shortened entries for other categories)
    {
      id: 12,
      name: 'Ice Creams',
      slug: 'ice-creams',
      menus: [
        {
          name: 'Chocolate Ice Cream',
          slug: 'chocolate-ice-cream',
          image: 'image-url',
          content: 'Intense chocolate flavor.',
          price: '12 TL'
        },
        {
          name: 'Vanilla Ice Cream',
          slug: 'vanilla-ice-cream',
          image: 'image-url',
          content: 'Classic vanilla taste.',
          price: '10 TL'
        },
        {
          name: 'Hazelnut Ice Cream',
          slug: 'hazelnut-ice-cream',
          image: 'image-url',
          content: 'Enjoy hazelnut ice cream.',
          price: '15 TL'
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
})
const scrollContainer = ref()
const buttonContainerRef = ref()
const listRef = ref([]);

const scrollTo = (slug) => {
  // First, let's find the target list based on the slug value
  const targetList = state.list.find(list => list.slug === slug);

  // If the target list is found, proceed
  if (targetList) {
    // Find the index value of the target list
    const targetIndex = state.list.indexOf(targetList);

    // If a valid index value exists, proceed
    if (targetIndex !== -1 && listRef.value[targetIndex]) {
      // Perform the scrolling operation
      listRef.value[targetIndex].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});

      // Update the active list
      state.active = slug;
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid target index or list item");
    }
  } else {
    console.error("Target list not found");
  }
};

const handleScroll = () => {
  // Get the scroll container
  const container = scrollContainer.value;
  // Get the current scroll position
  const top = container.scrollTop;
  // Get the elements on the page
  const hashElements = listRef.value;

  // Check for each element
  hashElements.forEach(hashElement => {
    const distance = top - hashElement.offsetTop;
    const hash = hashElement.dataset.href;

    // If the element is in the middle of the screen and is not currently active, make it active
    if (distance < 30 && distance > -30 && state.active !== hash) {
      state.active = hash;
    }
  });

  // If at the bottom of the page, make the last element active
  if (container.scrollHeight - top === container.clientHeight) {
    state.active = hashElements[hashElements.length - 1].dataset.href;
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  // Add the scroll event listener when the component is mounted
  const container = scrollContainer.value;
  container.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  // Remove the scroll event listener when the component is unmounted
  const container = scrollContainer.value;
  container.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
});
```

scroll listening was done

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that you don't know how to dynamically use ref in a list of elements

```js
 <div class="relative" v-for="(list,index) in state.list"  :ref="(element)=>listRef[index]=element" :data-href="list.slug"  :key="list.slug">
  ...
    const listRef = ref([])
 listRef.value[targetIndex].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

Comment: Where will I do this?